# Adding a duration to a stopover/waypoint on Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is is possible or are there any plans to allow way points that are stopovers to have a duration added to them that is then in turn added to the overall trip duration?

For example:

1. start at A
2. go via B as a stopover, wait 60 minutes
3. end at C

Either A to B or B to C should be reported as 60 minutes longer than the raw trip time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include this information in your question to help others answer.